# Assignment one item from two?

Tags: list, verilog, variable-assignment

I've been studying Verilog for a while and recently came across a kind of statement that I do not understand. Here is an example:

```
reg s_axis_data_tready_reg = 1'b0, s_axis_data_tready_next;
```

Looks like a concatenation but doesn't have the curly brackets surrounding the two items separated by a comma.  This statement compiles with no error.  What does this statement do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement declares 2 1-bit signals as type `reg`, and it also initializes one of them to `1'b0` (`s_axis_data_tready_reg`).  The other (`s_axis_data_tready_next`) has the value `x` (unknown), which is the default value for a `reg`.

```
module tb;

reg s_axis_data_tready_reg = 1'b0, s_axis_data_tready_next;

initial begin
    #1 $display("reg=%b, next=%b", s_axis_data_tready_reg, s_axis_data_tready_next);
end

endmodule
```

This outputs:

```
reg=0, next=x
```

Since it does not use curly braces: `{}`, it is not a concatenation.

Your single line can be also written as 2 lines:

```
reg s_axis_data_tready_reg = 1'b0;
reg s_axis_data_tready_next;
```